# Make Pagination using Ajax with Jquery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

This is the first time that I have make (I mean, I try) pagination without page refresh by using Ajax with Jquery, PHP and Mysql.

Problem: Pagination links are not working.

Site content is working.
This is a link to the test page: [testpage1](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/testsite1/public/index.php)

Thank you in advance for your help.

**1. Ajax(index.php)**

```
  <div id="page"> 

  </div>

<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      load_data();  
      function load_data(page)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"pagination2.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#page').html(data);  
                }  
           })  
      }  
      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
           var page = $(this).attr("id");  
           load_data(page);  
      });   
 });  
 </script>
```

**2. PHP (pagination2.php)**

```
if($page_nb > 1) {
    echo "<a href='index_all.php?page=".$prev_page."'>Back</a>";
    //echo '<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="LoadData('.$prev_page.')">Back</span>';

}

if ( $products_count > $check ) {

    for ( $i = max( 1, $page_nb - 5 ); $i <= min( $page_nb + 5, $limit ); $i++ ) {
        if ( $current_page == $i ) {
            echo "<span class=\"selected\">{$i}</span>";
        } else {
            //echo "<a href=\"{$url}?page=" . $i . "\">{$i}</a>";
            echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>"; 
        }
      }
    }   



if ($products_count > $check) { 

$next_page = $page_nb + 1;  
    echo "<a href='index_all.php?page=".$next_page."'>Next</a>";
    //echo '<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="LoadData('.$next_page.')">Next</span>';

}
```

**3. I think I found a solution**

**A. Ajax**

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      load_data();  
      function load_data(page)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"pagination2.php",  
                method:"GET",  
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#page').html(data);
                     //alert('Successfully called');
                }, 
              //error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);} 
           })  
      }  
     //load_data(1);

      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
           var page = $(this).attr("id");  
           load_data(page);  
      });  


 });  
 </script>
```

**B. Links**

```
if($page_nb > 1) {
    //echo "<a href='index_all.php?page=".$prev_page."'>Back</a>";
    echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$prev_page."'>Back</span>";

}

if ( $products_count > $check ) {

    for ( $i = max( 1, $page_nb - 5 ); $i <= min( $page_nb + 5, $limit ); $i++ ) {
        if ( $current_page == $i ) {
            echo "<span class=\"selected\">{$i}</span>";
        } else {
            //echo "<a href=\"{$url}?page=" . $i . "\">{$i}</a>";
            echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>"; 
        }
      }
    }   



if ($products_count > $check) { 

$next_page = $page_nb + 1;  
    //echo "<a href='index_all.php?page=".$next_page."'>Next</a>";
    echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$next_page."'>Next</span>";

}
```

Comment: It works now for me. Next step could be to use same page (use always first page and remove ``pagination2.php``), when call with ajax change url params dinamically and use client side rendering. So ppl can share link to any page an still use ajax.

Comment: Can you give an some example in the code?